# Cant seem to change my CSS code in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

A newbie here so I wanted to remove this section of the padding on my website.
[image]

As you can see I found to location of the code and changed the padding to 0px
[image]

However, no matter how much I change it is still the same padding and i can't seem to change it. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Code must be typed in as text. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and `edit` accordingly. It's too difficult to read text in images, especially on mobile as I'm on right now. Los, however, we need to be able to copy-paste the text you've entered into our editors and answers. Read the section about minimal reproducible examples also. All the best.

Comment: Have you tried opening the page in in-cognito/private mode? It could be just cache serving old file that you are not able to see your changes.

Comment: Are you using a child theme? If so, do you have your styles enqueued properly? If you're loading multiple stylesheets they could be loading in the wrong order and overriding your change.

Comment: It seems like it worked.@SyedAffanHamdani I think it was the cache then, good call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Theme Customizer - Additional CSS. Rules added there will override equivalent ones in the theme stylesheet in a standard installation. Assuming that setting site-content to 0 padding works, you can then determine whether caching or load order or some other feature or peculiarity of your site or how you're operating is preventing the new rule or rule set from taking effect.

Comment: I tried using the theme customizer additional CSS however it was still the same, however after using incognito mode, it seems to be fine now.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, but, if you think the problem has been solved, that's certainly good enough for me.